# json schema validation on aws lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-lambda, json-schema-validator

i need to validate my aws lambda event schema. i used ***vandium*** for validation. i have two diffrent cases.

1. lambda function support only one type of event.

like this

```
var vandium = require('vandium');

vandium.validation({
    name: vandium.types.string().required()
});

exports.handler = vandium(function (event, context, callback) {
    console.log('hello: ' + event.name);
    callback(null, 'Hello from Lambda');
});
```

in this case, ***vandium*** only validate , if key is present or not. But i need to check if any extra key is present or not.

2. lambda function support multiple type of events.

like this

```
var vandium = require('vandium');

vandium.validation({

    operation: vandium.types.string().required(),
    name: vandium.types.string().required(), });

exports.handler = vandium(function (event, context, callback) {

    const operation = event.operation;
    switch (operation) {
        case 'test1':
            test1(event);
            break;
        case 'test2':
            test2(event);
            break;

        default:
            callback(new Error("Unrecognized operation=" + operation));
            break;
    }


    function test1(event) {
        //console.log('hello: ' + event.name);
        callback(null, 'Hello from Lambda');
    }

    function test2(event) {
        //console.log('hello: ' + event.name);
        callback(null, 'Hello from Lambda');
    }

});
```

in this case, events for test1 & test2 are diffrent. like this

> test1{"name":"hello","id":100 }
>
> test2{"schoolName":"threni","teacher":"abcd" }

1. Which is the best scema validation npm package for problem like
   this?
2. is ***vandium*** is suitable for json validation.?

Comment: Hi, have you been successful with the JSON validation in your lambda function? Have you used ajv in the end?

Answer (score 2):

have you taken a look at [ajv](https://github.com/tutsplus/ajv) ? like in [Validating Data With JSON-Schema](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/validating-data-with-json-schema-part-1--cms-25343)

Comment: have you had any joy using ajv in a lambda function? Although it does not error, i am unable to perform any validation whatsoever.

Comment: > any joy using ajv in a lambda function?

I have had extensive success using AJV in a lambda function

Answer (score 1):

for those who need to validate events on aws lambda functions,@middy/validator would help.in this example case,you need to
step 1:

```
import validator from '@middy/validator';
```

step2:define a schema

```
const schema = {
  properties: {
    body: {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        name: {
          type: 'string',
        },
      },
      required: ['name'],
    },
  },
  required: ['body'],
};
```

step3:use the validator middleware

```
export const handler = Your_Lambda_Function
  .use(validator({ inputSchema: schema }));
```